# Excel Formula - Count of compared dates

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I am trying to make a formula to count the number of jobs that are either scheduled or completed and have their scheduled date on or before their due date. This is what I've come up with:

```
=countifs('DATABASE UPLOAD'!N:N,ARRAYFORMULA("COMPLETED", "SCHEDULED"),'DATABASE UPLOAD'!M:M,"<=" & 'DATABASE UPLOAD'!J:J)
```

Column N being job status, Column M being the Scheduled date and Column J is the Due date.

This keeps returning a 0 result, so I tried splitting up the array into individual countifs like this

```
=countifs('DATABASE UPLOAD'!N:N,"COMPLETED",'DATABASE UPLOAD'!M:M,"<=" & 'DATABASE UPLOAD'!J:J,'DATABASE UPLOAD'!N:N,"SCHEDULED",'DATABASE UPLOAD'!M:M,"<=" & 'DATABASE UPLOAD'!J:J)
```

But this also returns a 0 result. I think the issue is that it is comparing the whole column against the other column instead of comparing each line and telling me the total, but I am unsure how to have the formula check each line.

Comment: Could you please share some test data with expected results? Even a demo sheet.  It gets confusing otherwise and difficult to help you. Also please decide excel or Google sheets?

Comment: @marikamitsos here is a sheet, i've edited out any identifying data but it should still work https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JfQmNzxD3apoyHWxiUi57jkAMC02udsHJk2uBm2cjeI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking your sheet, it looks like you have issues with your dates.

1. Your `DATABASE UPLOADS` dates sheet may be on a different locale from that one of your sheet.
2. Your columns `F`, `G`, `H`, `K` are not even formatted as dates.
   You should change that by going to the top menu, `Format` -->`Number` -->`Date`

Should you fix those issues, your formulas will work as expected.